# Download HTTP thru sockets (C)

Tags: html, c, download, freeze, recv

Recently I started taking [this guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to get myself started on downloading files from the internet. I read it and came up with the following code to download the HTTP body of a website. The only problem is, it's not working. The code stops when calling the recv() call. It does not crash, it just keeps on running. Is this my fault? Am I using the wrong approch? I intent to use the code to not just download the contents of .html-files, but also to download other files (zip, png, jpg, dmg ...). I hope there's somebody that can help me. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> /* SOCKET */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct addrinfo */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit() */
#include <string.h> /* memset() */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <unistd.h> /* close() */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* IP Conversion */

#include <stdarg.h> /* va_list */

#define SERVERNAME "developerief2.site11.com"
#define PROTOCOL "80"
#define MAXDATASIZE 1024*1024

void errorOut(int status, const char *format, ...);
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int status;

    // GET ADDRESS INFO
    struct addrinfo *infos; 
    struct addrinfo hints;

    // fill hints
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;

    // get address info
    status = getaddrinfo(SERVERNAME, 
                         PROTOCOL, 
                         &hints, 
                         &infos);
    if(status != 0)
        errorOut(-1, "Couldn't get addres information: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));

    // MAKE SOCKET
    int sockfd;

    // loop, use first valid
    struct addrinfo *p;
    for(p = infos; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        // CREATE SOCKET
        sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, 
                        p->ai_socktype, 
                        p->ai_protocol);
        if(sockfd == -1)
            continue;

        // TRY TO CONNECT
        status = connect(sockfd, 
                         p->ai_addr, 
                         p->ai_addrlen);
        if(status == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if(p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // LET USER KNOW
    char printableIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family,
              get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
              printableIP,
              sizeof(printableIP));
    printf("Connection to %s\n", printableIP);

    // GET RID OF INFOS
    freeaddrinfo(infos);

    // RECEIVE DATA
    ssize_t receivedBytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    printf("Start receiving\n");
    receivedBytes = recv(sockfd, 
                         buf, 
                         MAXDATASIZE-1, 
                         0);
    printf("Received %d bytes\n", (int)receivedBytes);
    if(receivedBytes == -1)
        errorOut(1, "Error while receiving\n");

    // null terminate
    buf[receivedBytes] = '\0';

    // PRINT
    printf("Received Data:\n\n%s\n", buf);

    // CLOSE
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    // IP4
    if(sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in *) sa)->sin_addr);

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *) sa)->sin6_addr);
}

void errorOut(int status, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(status);
}
```

Comment: If the intent is downloading files, not implementing HTTP, you'd be better of using a library such as cURL: http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to grab files using HTTP, then [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is probably your best bet in C.  However, if you are using this as a way to learn network programming, then you are going to have to learn a bit more about HTTP before you can retrieve a file.

What you are seeing in your current program is that you need to send an explicit request for the file before you can retrieve it.  I would start by reading through [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).  Don't try to understand it all - it is a lot to read for this example.  Read the [first section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1) to get an understanding of how HTTP works, then read sections [4, 5, and 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4) to understand the basic message format.

Here is an example of what an HTTP request for the stackoverflow Questions page looks like:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: stackoverflow.com:80\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Accept-Encoding: identity, *;q=0\r\n
\r\n
```

I believe that is a minimal request.  I added the CRLFs explicitly to show that a blank line is used to terminate the request header block [as described in RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5).  If you leave out the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.3) header, then the result document will probably be transfered as a gzip-compressed stream since HTTP allows for this explicitly unless you tell the server that you do not want it.

The server response also contains HTTP headers for the meta-data describing the response.  Here is an example of a response from the previous request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: nginx\r\n
Date: Sun, 01 Aug 2010 13:54:56 GMT\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Cache-Control: private\r\n
Content-Length: 49731\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" ... 49,667 bytes follow
```

This simple example should give you an idea what you are getting into implementing if you want to grab files using HTTP.  This is the best case, most simple example.  This isn't something that I would undertake lightly, but it is probably the best way to learn and appreciate HTTP.

If you are looking for a simple way to learn network programming, this is a decent way to start.  I would recommend picking up a copy of [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) and [UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551).  These are probably the best way to really learn how to write network-based applications.  I would probably start by writing an [FTP client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) since [FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) is a much simpler protocol to start with.

If you are trying to learn the details associated with HTTP, then:

1. Buy [HTTP: the Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565925092) and read it
2. Read [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) until you understand it

   - Try examples using `telnet server 80` and typing in requests by hand
   - Download the cURL client and use the `--verbose` and `--include` command line options so that you can see what is happening
3. Read [Fielding's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation_2up.pdf) until HTTP really makes sense.

Just don't plan on writing your own HTTP client for *enterprise use*.  You do not want to do that, trust me as one who has been maintaining such a mistake for a little while now...

Comment: I really, really, really want to thank you all for the quick response, especially D.Shawley. I guess downloading files wasn't going to be as easy as I thought, but I will certainly get this to work. I want this to work because I want to be independent from the curl library, and if it won't work... cURL will always be there.

Thanks,
ief2

Comment: @lef2.  You are quite welcome.  I will offer some advice though.  Using implementations of complex protocols that others make available is an important part of developing software.  I would embrace libraries like cURL, Apache Portable Runtime, Boost, and other popular libraries.  Writing everything yourself is a recipe for disaster.  It is a very good way to learn how a protocol works but a very bad way to utilize HTTP at the application layer.

Comment: I was agreeing with you until you mentioned APR, which is the biggest abomination I've ever seen in C...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, you have to implement the HTTP protocol. Downloading a file is not just a matter of connecting to the server, you have to send HTTP requests (along with proper HTTP header) before you get a response. After this, you would still need to parse the returned data to strip out more HTTP headers.

If you're just trying to download files using C, I suggest the [cURL library](http://curl.haxx.se/), which does the HTTP work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to send an HTTP request before expecting a response.
You code currently just waits for a response which never comes.

Also, don't write comments in all caps.